# Intellisense for JavaScript and DevExpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress

DevExpress components have many client side objects like ASPxClientComboBox, ASPxClientButton etc. which can be used in JavaScript. Is there any way or what JavaScript editor should I use to have code-complition (intellisense) for that JavaScript classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Visual Studio and follow the [instructions](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/04/20/how-to-get-devexpress-javascript-intellisense.aspx).